# HSQLDB integer type key automatic increment

Tags: sql, database, primary-key, hsqldb

I have a table on my HSQLDB database with integer type primary key that's like `2014000123`: 
the system automatically autoincrements the key generating the next key like `2014000124` when i create a new row.

Now once I made a mistake entering a row with something like `2104000222` and now the system generates key starting with the "2104" instead of "2014".

How can i solve this: I need to tell the system to step back from "2104" to "2014"

Answer (score 0):

You can change the identity column value:

```
 ALTER TABLE <table name> ALTER COLUMN <column name> RESTART WITH <new value>;
```